# is it haram to make buisness?

Tags: halal-haram, business

Am planing to make a conference room place. So they pay me to use the room. Is it haram cause when I charge them am not doing anything just letting them use the room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you are making a conference room to get hired and it is everyone right to pay you for that room.It's all about taking service of room created by your by your own money. Many things we do hire in our day to day life
1) Flats
2) Business Shop ... etc
  Shouldn't we pay for all this?.. Yes we need to pay for all this.
Hope your question is answered!